# Change text of anchor - Expand/Retract all using .toggle jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using .toggle to expand/retract individual divs with the click of an anchor and also have one anchor that will expand/retract all of the divs. When clicking the individual anchor the anchor text changes from a "+" to a "-". Currently when you click the expand/retract all anchor the individual anchor text does not change - I would like them to change from "+" to "-" when the expand/retract all anchor is clicked. Below is my code - all is working except for the changing of the anchor text on the expand all:

HTML:

```
<a class="expand-all" href="#">+ Expand All</a>

<a class="toggle toggle-engine" href="#">+</a>
<div class="expand specs-engine"></div>

<a class="toggle toggle-body" href="#">+</a>
<div class="expand specs-engine"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('.expand').click(function() {$(this).toggle(400);});
$('.expand-all').click(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == '+ Expand All')
    $('.expand').show(400).find('.toggle').text('-');
  else
    $('.expand').hide(400).find('.toggle').text('+');
  $(this).text($(this).text() == '+ Expand All' ? '- Retract All' : '+ Expand All');
});


$('.toggle-engine').click(function() {
    $('.specs-engine').toggle(400);
$(this).text($(this).text() == '+' ? '-' : '+');
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.expand').click(function() {$(this).toggle(400);});
$('.expand-all').click(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == '+ Expand All')
    $('.expand').show(400).prev('.toggle').text('-');
  else
    $('.expand').hide(400).prev('.toggle').text('+');
  $(this).text($(this).text() == '+ Expand All' ? '- Retract All' : '+ Expand All');
});


$('.toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.expand').toggle(400);
    $(this).text($(this).text() == '+' ? '-' : '+');
    return false;
});
```

I changed `find` to `prev`, that should make the text change work. The bottom part is a "bonus", if you do it like this you don't have to write the same code for every item.

Comment: Still no luck. The individual ones work great but the expand all is not changing the individual anchor text.

Comment: Try `prev` instead of `next` :)

Answer (score 0):

Hows this: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hjTea/)**

The example starts with all elements visible.

```
$('.expand').click(function() {$(this).toggle(400);});

$('.expand-all').click(function() {
  $(this).text($(this).text() == '+ Expand All' ? '- Retract All' : '+ Expand All');
  if ($(this).text() == '+ Expand All')
  {
      $('a.toggle').text('+');
      $('div.expand').slideUp();
  }
  else
  {
      $('a.toggle').text('-');
      $('div.expand').slideDown();
  }
});

$('.toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.expand').toggle(400);
    $(this).text($(this).text() == '+' ? '-' : '+');
});
```